# Looping through array contain 3 classes

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am having trouble getting my head around how to loop through stdClasses.

Printing the array gives me the following:

```
Array
(
    [piggyback] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1003
                    [entity_id] => 0
                    [redirect_url] => http://yahoo.com
                    [type] => Image
                )

        )

    [total_count] => 1
)
Array
(
    [piggyback] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1002
                    [entity_id] => 0
                    [redirect_url] => http://google.com
                    [type] => Image
                )

        )

    [total_count] => 1
)
Array
(
    [piggyback] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1001
                    [entity_id] => 0
                    [redirect_url] => http://bing.com
                    [type] => Image
                )

        )

    [total_count] => 1
```

I am trying to loop though with the following and print out a value (id) but I keep getting nothing.

```
foreach ($piggies_array as $key => $value) {
  echo $piggies_array[$key]['id'];
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify how you printed the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($piggies_array as $key => $value) {
if (is_array($value)){
  echo $value[0]->id;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to you and to all. Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($piggies_array); $i++) {
    echo $piggies_array[$i]['piggyback'][0]->id;
}
```

...assuming we can only see part of your output ;)

Answer (score 0):

try replace it to `echo $value->id;`